# Appending date in FileName - Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have got this

FileName = "Events_Data.csv"

I want to add date to this, so output required is

FileName = "Events_Data_20140521.csv"

I have got data in separate variables, just don't know how to add this before .csv in the file name.

Can anyone please help.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chech below code

**VB.Net**

```
Dim FileName As String = "Events_Data.csv"
FileName = FileName.Replace(".csv", "_" & System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".csv")
```

**C#.Net**

```
string FileName = "Events_Data.csv";
string ptest =System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
FileName = FileName.Replace(".csv", "_" + ptest  + ".csv");
```

Comment: I need to write this in C# and this System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") will be a variable. Can you help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim FileName As String = "Your File Name"
FileName += DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyHHmm") + _
            System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)

FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Upload/" + FileName))
FileName = "Upload/" + FileName
```

Comment: Can you please provide a brief explanation.

Comment: this should be DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm") otherwise it will give you minutes, not months :)

Answer (score 0):

You **concatenate** the various parts using &:

```
FileName = "Events_Data_" & yourDateVariable & ".csv"
```

Comment: FileName = "Events_Data.csv" - so first I will need to use substring function to split the above then add them and then concatenate them again

Comment: You could do, but if its going to be "Events_Data" ... ".csv" then you could ignore the current value of FileName.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if varDate is Type Date

```
FileName = FileName.Replace(".csv", String.Format("_{0}.csv", varDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")))
```

or
is just a String

```
FileName = FileName.Replace(".csv", String.Format("_{0}.csv", varDate))
```